# Remove an element from list and return the result

Tags: python, list

I want to generate a list which looks like:

```
['ret-120','ret-115','ret-110',....'ret-5','ret5',....'ret240']
```

Please note, there's no `ret0` element in the list. So I have to remove it from a list populated by range function. I've tried:

```
['ret'+str(x) for x in list(range(-120,241,5)).remove(0)]
```

However this gives out an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Is this possible to accomplish with one line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want is to add a conditional inside your list comprehension:

```
lst = ['cumRet'+str(x) for x in xrange(-120,241,5) if x != 0]
# This part:                                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

I also removed the unnecessary list creation and changed `range`->`xrange` (note that this `range`->`xrange` change is Python2 only)

Answer (score 2):

Your `NoneType` error is because `list.remove(index)` modifies in-place, so it returns `None`.

Hence, you are trying to loop `[for x in None]`.

2-line alternate way (with `;`)

```
tmp = list(range(-120,241,5));tmp.remove(0)
['ret'+str(x) for x in list(range(-120,241,5)).remove(0)]
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know what is the correct way to write the code?

Comment: @user2854008, there is no one-liner since `remove` is a method, but you can make it into three lines, check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `list.remove()` method changes the list in-place and effectively returns `None`, but you can skip `x` when it's zero like this:

```
['ret'+str(x) for x in range(-120, 241, 5) if x]
```

If you're using Python 2, `range()` could be changed to `xrange()` which would avoid creating a temporary list of all the integer values.

Answer (score 0):

**remove() return None**

The list `remove()` method return `None`, So 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Demo:

```
>>> b = list(range(-120,241,5)).remove(0)
>>> b
>>> print b
None
```

We will create variable of list and then remove `0` from it.

Demo:

```
>>> tmp = list(range(-120,241,5))
>>> tmp.remove(0)
>>> ['cumRet'+str(x) for x in tmp]
['cumRet-120', 'cumRet-115', 'cumRet-110', 'cumRet-105', 'cumRet-100', 'cumRet-95', 'cumRet-90', 'cumRet-85', 'cumRet-80', 'cumRet-75', 'cumRet-70', 'cumRet-65', 'cumRet-60', 'cumRet-55', 'cumRet-50', 'cumRet-45', 'cumRet-40', 'cumRet-35', 'cumRet-30', 'cumRet-25', 'cumRet-20', 'cumRet-15', 'cumRet-10', 'cumRet-5', 'cumRet5', 'cumRet10', 'cumRet15', 'cumRet20', 'cumRet25', 'cumRet30', 'cumRet35', 'cumRet40', 'cumRet45', 'cumRet50', 'cumRet55', 'cumRet60', 'cumRet65', 'cumRet70', 'cumRet75', 'cumRet80', 'cumRet85', 'cumRet90', 'cumRet95', 'cumRet100', 'cumRet105', 'cumRet110', 'cumRet115', 'cumRet120', 'cumRet125', 'cumRet130', 'cumRet135', 'cumRet140', 'cumRet145', 'cumRet150', 'cumRet155', 'cumRet160', 'cumRet165', 'cumRet170', 'cumRet175', 'cumRet180', 'cumRet185', 'cumRet190', 'cumRet195', 'cumRet200', 'cumRet205', 'cumRet210', 'cumRet215', 'cumRet220', 'cumRet225', 'cumRet230', 'cumRet235', 'cumRet240']
>>>
```

---

**Exception Handling:**

Best practice to do `Exception Handling` when we went to remove element from the list because if element not present in the list then it will raise `ValueError` exception.

Demo:

```
>>> l = [4,6,8]
>>> l.remove(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
>>> 
>>> try:
...   l.remove(3)
... except ValueError:
...   print "List not contains remove element."
... 
List not contains remove element.
>>>
```